# Significant Change updates when device is locked

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

After some testing I am noticing that there is a major difference in the effectiveness of significant change monitoring when the device is locked.

My app does significant change monitoring. When the device is turned on and my app is in the foreground or background significant change works well. When the device is locked it takes a lot longer for significant change to fire off. Meaning when the device is on it fires off probably in around 500 meters or so. When the device is locked it is a lot more random and I can go miles without it firing off.

Again it does not matter if my app is in the foreground or the background but it changes a lot when the device is locked.

Does anyone know of any documentation about this or have any experience with this?

I have done less testing on it but the same also seems to be true about region monitoring which I know works similar to significant change.

Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: It could happen because WiFi has been shutdown to save battery when the phone is locked. Are you trying with 3G on also?

Comment: Yes, 3G is on. I think your point on Wifi could be true but I am not sure how to get around it.